# Entity framework, when call ToList() it will load FK objects automatically?

Tags: entity-framework-4, lazy-loading, poco

I am kind of confused about how Lazy loading working.

For example if I have supplier object, which have Address foreign object as a property, like this:

```
public class Supplier
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string TaxNumber { get; set; }
        public virtual Address DeliveryAddress { get; set; }
}
```

when I put a break point at:

```
var suppliers = dbContext.Supplier.ToList();
```

I can see that Address information are available to the var suppliers, etc. when I expend the DeliveryAddress property, it is avaliable, is that means all the FK object has been loaded? But on the other hand, for the query on the right hand I can view that from Visual Studio at the break point, and it is like that:

```
{SELECT 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[FullName] AS [FullName], 
[Extent1].[TaxNumber] AS [TaxNumber], 
[Extent1].[DeliveryAddress_ID] AS [DeliveryAddress_ID]
FROM [dbo].[Suppliers] AS [Extent1]}
```

Which means the query itself wouldn't tying to load the Address object at all?

So who is loading the FK objects? ToList() or VS debugger?

Other suggestion about how to confirm that whether it is Lazy loading or not?

Note: So now I confirmed that Lazy loading is working by two ToList call, one set Lazy loading off, and another set lazy loading on. Could someone point me to a way to know at what point when lazy loading another query was sent for FK property?

Comment: How are you determining that the DeliveryAddress has already been loaded eagerly/non-lazily? Are you sure there was only 1 query sent to the db? You can start SQL Profiler to see exactly what queries are sent to the db.

Comment: Hi, How could I start SQL Profiler? I am using SQL Server 2008 R2, and don't seems have the SQL Profiler menu avaliable. I can only see: Import and Export, Server Management Studio, Configuration tools, Integration services?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The VS debugger loads the related object and it happens with a second SQL query, not the one you have shown in your question. When you drill into the address object in the debugger, the debugger accesses properties of the object to display their values. Accessing this object triggers lazy loading and the second SQL query.

**Edit**

This works because the parent object is not your `Supplier` type but a class which is derived from `Supplier` (a "proxy"). This derived class is created dynamically at runtime and has some cryptic autogenerated name (you should see this class name in the debugger). This dynamic class has the same properties as your base `Supplier` but it has overloaded the `DeliveryAddress` property. (That's the reason why those navigation properties must be `virtual`, otherwise overloading wouldn't be possible.) The query uses the FK column value which has already been fetched with your supplier query and retrieves the address by this value.

The new getter of the overloaded `DeliveryAddress` property which is called when you or the debugger accesses the property with `supplier.DeliveryAddress` contains at runtime generated code which runs a SQL query to load the related object from the database. The derived proxy class holds various additional internal members, especially a reference to the context/database connection (to be able to run a query at all) and a flag which indicates for the proxy object that it already has loaded the navigation property, so that it doesn't run a second redundant query when you access the `DeliveryAddress` a second time.

That's in short the way how lazy loading with POCOs works.

Comment: @Salauma, thanks for the additional explanation, the original answer itself is good but sort of saying the obvious. Could you please suggest a way to find out when the query was sent for DeliveryAddress property? The problem with SQL Profiler is seems I need install it first.

Comment: @pstar: The query is sent in the moment when you click the + node in the VS debugger object tree to drill into the supplier's delivery address. The query which is sent is something like: `SELECT * FROM AdressTable WHERE AddressId = DeliveryAddress_ID`.

Comment: @Salauma, What I want see is the query for FK Objects fire in action. I was hoping that the query for DeliveryAddress wouldn't fire unless access the FK property, but couldn't confirm that.